# todo tags not working on eclipse and pydev

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, pydev, todo

I'm using eclipse 3.7.0 on fedora and pydev 2.2.2

I tried to use the todo tags but it doesnt work.
the todo tags on window > preferences looks fine.
i can add a using left click beside the line.

please advice

Comment: Always turn on your automatically build feature in Pydev IDE

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Comments with #TODO will only generate tasks if:

1. The code is in a source folder (i.e.: in the PYTHONPATH)
2. You have the builders turned on (or run the build manually from time to time).

Reference: http://pydev.org/manual_adv_tasks.html

The getting started guide ( http://pydev.org/manual_101_root.html ) has instructions on how to config PyDev properly so that things like todo tasks work properly

Answer (score 14):

Make sure you are writing:

```
#TODO: This is my todo.
```

Otherwise, it won't work. Note the colon after the 'O'.

Comment: semi-colon ; colon: I am pretty sure you are refering to colon