# TODO tags aren't found in Eclipse with PyDev

Tags: python, eclipse, svn, tags, todo

I'm using Eclipse with PyDev on OpenSUSE 12.1. I've got projects in Javascript and Python. By right click I can add a TODO, but since I'm working with other developers I'd like to have them as code comments so that they get synchronized with the rest of the code by SVN.

I looked at this thread: [todo tags not working on eclipse and pydev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510652/todo-tags-not-working-on-eclipse-and-pydev), but it sadly it didn't help. Here's a short summary of my setup:

- I'm running Eclipse 64 bit, but that shouldn't be a problem
- The preferences under PyDev --> Task Tags are configured correctly, they're set to find "TODO:"
- In Preferences --> General --> Editors --> Structured Text Editors --> Task Tags, searching for task tags is enabled and set to search for TODO
- In Project --> Properties --> PyDev - PYTHONPATH my source folders are listed under source folders.

The one thing that I think might be leading to it is that in Preferences --> General --> Editors --> Structured Text Editors --> Task Tags, the filters are set to only search for CSS, DTD, HTML, JSP and XML. But there's no option to have Eclipse also search PYs. Could that be causing the problem? Thanks!

Comment: No, that sounds like it's handled by PyDev instead, when you Build.  You have let it Build, right?

Comment: @nitind, yes, I've set the project to build automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe your file is under a source folder but is still not considered a Python module (i.e.: has some strange name with a separator or something... or maybe it's not in a folder with `__init__.py` files).

It'd be interesting to know a bit more on the structure you're using... a screenshot with your editor and the path in the pydev package explorer would be nice to help in diagnosing your problem.

Comment: ![Screenshot of Eclipse with PYTHONPATH, TODO, empty TODO list and source folder](http://137.248.191.62:8080/pictures/snapshot1.png)

I'm no expert on Python (as much as I'd like to be), but as far as I understand it `__init__.py` is needed so that the folder is seen as containing modules, right? I've got `__init__.py` in the folder, but it's empty. Screenshot above. As you can see, I do have a TODO in the code (right above the properties window) but in the view at the bottom no tasks are recognized. Altogether I have about 20 TODOs in that file.

Comment: The problem is that your PYTHONPATH is not well defined: isis.horizon is not a valid name for a python package (i.e.: it'll not be possible to import it). So, to fix your issue, do the following: remove the 'horizon_optimization' item from the PYTHONPATH and leave only 'horizon_optimization/isis.horizon' -- you may have to do a rebuild (or just change that file) so that TODO tasks are found.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I now took out 'horizon_optimization' and left only '/horizon_optimization/isis.horizon' in there. After that I waited a few seconds, since the project's set to build automatically, then I switched automatic building off, built it again, and restarted eclipse. None of that got the todos to show though :( Would it perhaps help to rename the folder 'isis.horizon' to something like 'isis_horizon' or just 'horizon'?

Comment: It'll only build automatically changed files... if you want to force, you should do a project > clean. The name of the source folder shouldn't matter much (only the name of the package must be a valid python name).

Comment: Okay, that worked - I think one of the file names was just too long. As soon as I shortened it it worked fine. Thanks a lot, now my todos show up right away!